# My Computer Doesn't Start Up

Tags: windows-vista, boot, power, acer-aspire

I'm using an Acer Aspire L320(Windows Vista) and have no idea what happened to it! It doesn't start up (no visual on my monitor at all) and although the power button LED light still comes on, the 'beep' sound that used to come along with the start up doesn't anymore!

It has been acting up a little recently, like taking longer to start up and taking a while for the visual on the monitor to appear but everything else seemed to be working fine so i just left it as it was.

And I was wondering if it's a hardware problem would it be easy to fix it myself and salvage my data?

Thanks in advance! :)

Oh and just to add on, I tested the monitor and the power cord, they're not the cause of the problem!

Comment: Your data is probably safe on your hard drive, so if everything else fails you can just copy it over to a new PC. But of course it doesn't mean that buying new PC is your only option. I hope you'll get it fixed, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I know the reply is a lil late but I decided to skip the hassle and just get a new PC. I did check the fan, PSU, RAM, thermal paste. All seemed to be fine so I presumed it's a processor or motherboard issue.

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to a number of things, narrow the possibilities down by removing (where possible) the component and checking it for obvious faults.

**This is how i would do it:**

1. Check that the CPU fan is spinning on startup
2. Check if there is any/enough thermal paste between heat sink and CPU
3. Remove the RAM Sticks and try booting with single sticks to see if it's a faulty stick
4. Swap the PSU out for another...
5. If all else fails, swapping the graphics card for another would be worth a try

**If nothing in the boot process changes:**

Motherboard...?! At this point the question you have to ask yourself is wether or not it actually makes sense to spend hours (eventually days) tracking down the problem, or wether it's better to build/buy a new system...obviously depends on wether this is purely private and fun/hobby or if you really need to get some work done and don't need this. Replacing a not so new Aspire L320 shouldn't cost a lot (especially in comparison to the hours spent trying to fix it).

**By the way:**

Continue posting your results as you try solving this, someone might have had the exact component/problem and can add to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with an Aspire R7 that would sometimes not wake from sleep or standby.  I found somewhere that when the laptop is not responding correctly, do a hard reset.  There is not a way to remove the battery, but there is a tiny pinhole in the back or under side. Has a battery like icon. Press is for about 5 seconds and let go. Turn on your laptop.  If everything looks normal, cool. If not, please take notes on what you see and error codes for more troubleshooting. Hope this helps, take care! ~Lucy

Answer (score -3):

if the motherboard logo doesn't appear it must be the graphic card that is damaged somehow if not try too boot with a rescue disk such as Kaspersky's to eliminate viruses that could be holding the boot process

Comment: Why graphics? It could be anything. Especially the 'beep' thing suggests it's not graphics.